# mysql procedure not working for searching 2 column values in the table?

Tags: mysql

i have written the query like this:

```
select * from c_course where c_course.cdesc LIKE CONCAT('%',"science",'%')
OR  c_course.cname LIKE CONCAT('%',"science",'%');
cid     cname      cdesc      sdate         edate
'301', 'physics', 'science', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-06'
'303', 'chemistry', 'science', '2013-01-09', '2013-01-09'
'501', 'science', 'natural science', '2013-01-31', '2013-01-09'
```

its working properly. same i have written using stored procedure like this:

```
use lportal;
delimiter //
create procedure pro_search143(IN sname varchar(20))
begin

SET @c = CONCAT('"',sname,'"');

select * from c_course where 

c_course.cdesc LIKE CONCAT('%',c,'%')
OR 
c_course.cname LIKE CONCAT('%',c,'%');

end
//
```

its executing but while calling the procedure it showing the error like this:

CALL pro_search143("science"); unknown column in c where clause.

can any one modify my code and give solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this :

```
 use lportal;
 delimiter //
 create procedure pro_search143(IN sname varchar(20))
 begin

 SET @query = concat('select * 
                      from c_course 
                      where c_course.cdesc LIKE CONCAT(''%'',''',sname,''',''%'') 
                         OR c_course.cname LIKE CONCAT(''%'',''',sname,''',''%'');
                     ');

 PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
 EXECUTE stmt;

 end //
```

And with : `call pro_search143("science")`

Comment: use lportal;
call pro_search143(science);
 unkown column 'science' in 'filed list', i have tried what us aid is not working same error again

Comment: Try with call pro_search143("science");

Comment: i have tried but it does not showing any list..like empty list

Answer (score 0):

You define a variable `@c` but you use `c`. You missed the `@`.

But why not just

```
select * from c_course 
where cdesc LIKE CONCAT('%',sname,'%')
OR cname LIKE CONCAT('%',sname,'%');
```

Looking at your examples you could even do

```
select * from c_course 
where sname in (cdesc, cname)
```

which is way better in performance than doing a wildcard search.

Comment: i have tried it! it is also showing same thing while passing science showing unknown column science in field list